# collapse rows using sql stuff function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have three tables in my sql database and i am trying to collapse rows in sql server using stuff function from 3 tables

i had try inner join and left outer to do so but didn't get result as expected
my code is at below:

```
select T1.Id, 
       T1.Name,
       T2.Id,
       T2.T1_Id,
       T2.Name,
       stuff(
       (
           select ','+T3.Name 
           from Test3 T3 
           where T3.Id=T2.T3_Id for xml path('')
       ),1,1,'') as Test5
from Test1 T1,Test2 T2 
where T1.Id=T2.T1_Id
```

i got result like

```
Id  Name    Id  T1_Id   Name    Test5
----------------------------------------------
1   Test1   1    1      ASD      BAAN
1   Test1   2    1      ASD      KAAL
```

expected

```
Id  Name    Id  T1_Id   Name    Test5
1   Test1   1     1      ASD  BAAN,KAAL
```

my tables scripts and sample data is and i am using sql server 2014

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test1](
        [Id] [int] NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test1]
           ([Id]
           ,[Name])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'Test1')
           GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test2](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [T1_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [T3_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test2]
           ([Id]
           ,[T1_Id]
           ,[T3_Id]
           ,[Name])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,1
           ,1
           ,'ASD'),(2,1,2,'ASD')
           GO


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test3](
        [Id] [int] NULL,
        [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

   INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test3]
           ([Id]
           ,[Name])
     VALUES
           (1
           ,'KAAL'),(2,'BAAL')
           Go
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Judging from the result you get, you have two different rows in Test2 with the same `T1_Id` value - but different `Id` value. That's why your join query returns two different rows (it has nothing to do with the subquery). BTW, if you are using SQL Server 2017 or higher, you better use the built in `string_agg` instead of the `stuff...for xml` combination. better for maintenance, better for performance.

Comment: but i have to use only stuff i cannot try 2017 sql server

Comment: Your edit is a good step in the right direction. Please fix the insert statement and add the specific version tag relevant to the SQL Server version you are using.

Comment: i am using sql server 2014

Comment: Just a remark... the "row collapsing" is not done by the STUFF function, but by the SELECT...FOR XML query. The STUFF function is just for removing the first (leading) separator from the concatenated result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "COLLAPSE" in SQL, the language. What you posted shows grouping and aggregating. For strings, the only meaningful aggregations are MIN, MAX and string concatenation.

SQL Server 2017 provides string concatenation through the `STRING_AGG` function. Other database products use different names, like `GROUP_CONCAT`. In earlier SQL Server versions various techniques are used to do the same. What you posted is the XML technique.

The query doesn't have a GROUP BY clause though, which is why multiple rows are returned.

In SQL Server 2017, the query would look like this :

```
select T1.Id, 
       T1.Name,
       MIN(T2.Id) as T2_ID,
       MIN(T2.T1_Id) as T1_ID,
       MIN(T2.Name) as T2_Name,
       STRING_AGG(T3.Name,', ') as Test5
from @Test1 T1 
    inner join @Test2 T2 on T1.Id=T2.T1_Id
    inner join @Test3 T3 on T3.Id=T2.T3_Id 
GROUP BY T1.ID,T1.Name
```

Doing the same in earlier versions is trickier. The `FOR XML` query can only correlate with columns that appear in the GROUP BY clause :

```
select T1.Id, 
       T1.Name,
       MIN(T2.Id),
       MIN(T2.T1_Id),
       MIN(T2.Name),
       stuff(
       (
           SELECT ','+T3.Name 
           FROM @Test3 T3 
              inner join @Test2 TT2 on T3.Id=TT2.T3_Id
           WHERE TT2.T1_ID=T1.Id 
           FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,1,'') as Test5
from @Test1 T1 
    inner join @Test2 T2 on T1.Id=T2.T1_Id
GROUP BY T1.ID,T1.Name
```

Think of the entire `STUFF(... FOR XML)..` part as a single function that takes as argument one of the grouping columns in the `WHERE` clause, searches some tables and concatenates the string results.

This means that the correlation clause

```
WHERE TT2.T1_ID=T1.Id
```

can only refer to the grouping columns in the outer query. We need a join with T2 in there because we can't get to T1.ID from T3 directly

If you don't care about the T2 columns, you can get rid of the JOIN in the outer query :

```
select T1.Id, 
       T1.Name,
       stuff(
       (
           select ','+T3.Name 
           from @Test3 T3 
              inner join @Test2 TT2 on T3.Id=TT2.T3_Id
              where TT2.T1_ID=T1.Id for xml path('')
       ),1,1,'') as Test5
from @Test1 T1 
GROUP BY T1.ID,T1.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT T1.Id AS T1_Id,
       T1.Name AS T1_Name,
       T2.Id  AS  T2_Id,
       T2.T1_Id AS T2_T1_Id,
       T2.Name AS T2_Name, 
       T3.Name AS Test5
FROM [Test2] t2
    INNER JOIN [Test1] t1
ON t1.Id = t2.T1_Id
    INNER JOIN [Test3] t3
ON t3.id = t2.T3_Id
)
SELECT  T1_Id,  
        T1_Name,            
        T2_T1_Id,   
        T2_Name,    
        STUFF((SELECT  ', '+Test5 
                FROM CTE i WHERE i.T1_Id = o.T1_Id 
                FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS Test5
FROM CTE o
GROUP BY T1_Id, 
        T1_Name,            
        T2_T1_Id,   
        T2_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about Test2.Name you can have result like below:

```
WITH tblMain as (SELECT T1.Id,T1.Name, T3.Name T3Name
                 FROM Test2 T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 Test1 T1 on T2.T1_Id = T1.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 Test3 T3 on T2.T3_Id = T3.Id)

SELECT Id, Name, 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + T3Name
           FROM tblMain b 
           WHERE b.Id = a.Id AND b.Name = a.Name 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') as Test5
FROM tblMain a
GROUP BY Id, Name
```

Otherwise if you want other columns from Test2, you should add them in `GROUP BY` clause too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following script.

**Note:** You have to avoid ID from Test2 and Test3 as other wise you can not apply GROUP BY for STUFF as they have different value in ID column.

```
SELECT *,
STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + Name 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT T3.Name
            FROM Test1 T1 
            INNER JOIN Test2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.T1_Id
            INNER JOIN Test3 T3 ON T2.T3_Id = T3.ID
        ) B
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
) Test5
FROM
(
    SELECT T1.Id,T1.Name T1_Name,T2.Name T2_Name
    FROM Test1 T1 
    INNER JOIN Test2 T2 ON T1.Id = T2.T1_Id
)A  
GROUP BY A.Id,A.T1_Name,A.T2_Name
```